# Add +1 to date upto 7days and other column value should be divided by 7 upto 7 rows in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Sample table:

| emp | date | sal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 698 | 28/11/2021 | 9200 |
| 724 | 02/01/2022 | 8700 |

output should be:

| emp | date | sal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 698 | 28/11/2021 | 1314 |
| 698 | 29/11/2021 | 1314 |
| 698 | 30/11/2021 | 1314 |
| 698 | 01/12/2021 | 1314 |
| 698 | 02/12/2021 | 1314 |
| 698 | 03/12/2021 | 1314 |
| 698 | 04/12/2021 | 1314 |
| 724 | 02/01/2022 | 1242 |
| 724 | 03/01/2022 | 1242 |
| 724 | 04/01/2022 | 1242 |
| 724 | 05/01/2022 | 1242 |
| 724 | 06/01/2022 | 1242 |
| 724 | 07/01/2022 | 1242 |
| 724 | 08/01/2022 | 1242 |

here, I should display, add +1 for the date upto 7days and sal should be divided by 7

Each row from the sample input should result as 7 rows in the sample output

I need a query in Oracle SQL

Comment: To make the problem more interesting - what if the "weekly" salary like 9200 is not exactly divisible by 7? Do you just divide by 7 and truncate the result? (Then the total salary over 7 days will generally be less than the promised weekly salary.) Do you round to two decimal places? Or do you truncate, but then as an additional step, allocate the remaining amounts over the last few days? For example, for 9200, the "daily" salary should be 1314, but in the last two days it should be 1315, to make up the total of exactly 9200, not 9198. (This may be a question for your business users!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `CROSS JOIN` with a row generator to create the 7 days:

```sql
SELECT t.emp,
       t."DATE" + d.days AS "DATE",
       TRUNC(t.sal / 7) AS sal
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS days
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
       ) d
ORDER BY emp, "DATE"
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (emp, "DATE", sal) AS
SELECT 698, DATE '2021-11-28', 9200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 724, DATE '2021-01-02', 8700 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMP | DATE | SAL |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 698 | 2021-11-28 00:00:00 | 1314 |
> | 698 | 2021-11-29 00:00:00 | 1314 |
> | 698 | 2021-11-30 00:00:00 | 1314 |
> | 698 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 1314 |
> | 698 | 2021-12-02 00:00:00 | 1314 |
> | 698 | 2021-12-03 00:00:00 | 1314 |
> | 698 | 2021-12-04 00:00:00 | 1314 |
> | 724 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 1242 |
> | 724 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 1242 |
> | 724 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 1242 |
> | 724 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 1242 |
> | 724 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 1242 |
> | 724 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 1242 |
> | 724 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 1242 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d11d5f6270bc718ed915315c1c0e14b7)*

Comment: Could you `connect by level` directly on the table without involving `dual`?

Comment: @Mureinik If you just add `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7` to the query on the table then it will generate duplicate rows as the connect by clause does not have a filter on the `EMP` to restrict it from connecting different `EMP`s at each level of the hierarchy. If you add that filter then you will get a `ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data` and then you get into all sorts of hacks like generating `SYS_GUID` values at each level to bypass that error [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=82d690de7a808798a117f13393b2d165). Its much simpler to `CROSS JOIN` a row generator .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compact way to do this - using a simple XQuery expression to generate numbers between 0 and 6:

```
select emp,
       date_ + xmlcast(column_value as number) as date_,
       round(sal/7, 2) as sal
from   table_name cross join xmltable('0 to 6')
;
```

Note - I changed the `date` column name to `date_` (with an underscore). `date` is a reserved keyword, it can't be a column name. Also, obviously, you will need to use your actual table name.